# How to grep the latest logfile in directory for value, logs update 100's lines per minute and wrap to new file every few minutes

Tags: linux, grep, tail, watch

Need to tail the latest log file in a directory, and grep it for a given value.  This works just fine:

tail -f `ls -rt logfiles* | tail -1` | grep

However, the log files are updated with dozens or even hundreds of lines per minute, and wrap anywhere from 1 minute to 10 minutes.

Need to use watch to run my tail command every interval and make sure I am tailing the latest log file.

Tried

> watch "tail -f `ls -rt logfiles* | tail -1` | grep "

and

> watch -N 10 "tail -f `ls -rt logfiles* | tail -1` | grep "

But they don't seem to do exactly what I need.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: so what does actually happen other than what you expect?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO as it is not about programming.  It belongs on [su].

Comment: It didn't show me any results.. but you're right I'll post on SU. Thanx